# Using intellij idea, how can I attach subversion to a project?

Tags: java, svn, intellij-idea

I am using intellij idea, how can I attach subversion config to a project? I can't find somewhere to add a repository, Am I missing anything else?

I don't want to check out again, it may cause inconsistency.

[browse subversion repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IviSN.png)

[no subversion info here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OSHQ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error at the bottom of your second screenshot. It is marked in red color. The error indicates that your SVN client is very old and is outdated. You must upgrade the client to the latest supported version which is now 1.9.x.

Comment: thanks, I understand that, but tortoiseSvn version and working copy vertion both are 1.7. so there is not supposed to be any conflict.

Comment: @nelson No. The working copy was created with newer SVN client. So there is a SVN client with newer version on your computer.